# Manipulating deep values of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to go from

```
first = 
{'a' : 
    {'b' :
        {'c' : ['d', 'e'],
         'f' : ['g']
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
z = 0
second = 
{'a' : 
    {'b' :
        {'c' : 
            {'d' : z, 
             'e' : z
             },
         'f' :
            {'g' : z}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for the pythonic way to do this.
I want to change every 3rd level elements of first (c and f) from a list to a dictionary where keys are the elements of the list (d, e for example).

Comment: Are there multiple keys in the first and second level dictionaries so that you would need to iterate there, or is it just a>b>...?

Comment: In my opinion, there isn't a shortcut to this process. Just write nested loop or long list comprehension.

Comment: Add a name: `third_level = first['a']['b']`, now you can work with `third_level` as with a regular dictionary (which it is). What's missing from the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> {k1: {k2: {k3: {k4:0 for k4 in v3} for k3, v3 in v2.items()} for k2, v2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in first.items()}
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'e': 0, 'd': 0}, 'f': {'g': 0}}}}
```

=)

(If you don't want to get shot in code review, stick to the advice by 9000 in the comments, please. I.e. get all third level dicts and manipulate those directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is your friend! It allows you to generalize the operation to the last level of a dictionary, which can be arbitrarily long and even not symmetric (e.g. having a branch with 5 levels and one with 3 levels).

```
first = \
{'a' : 
    {'b' :
        {'c' : ['d', 'e'],
         'f' : ['g']
        }
    }
}

def rec_list_to_dict(inp, sub_value = 0):

    if isinstance(inp, list):
        return dict(zip(inp, [sub_value ]*len(inp)))
    elif isinstance(inp, dict):
        return {key : rec_list_to_dict(el, sub_value) for key, el in inp.items()}
    else:
        raise AttributeError


second = rec_list_to_dict(first, sub_value = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice place to use the visitor pattern (not sure if it is considered a pattern, of course):

```
def visit_dict(d, new_value=None):
    new_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new_d[k] = visit_dict(v, new_value)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            new_d[k] = visit_list(v, new_value)
        else:
            new_d[k] = v
    return new_d

def visit_list(l, new_value=None):
    return {item: new_value for item in l}

first = {
    'a' : {
        'b' : {
            'c' : ['d', 'e'],
            'f' : ['g']
        }
    }
}

z = 0
print(visit_dict(first, z))

# {
#     'a' : {
#         'b' : {
#             'c' : {
#                 'd': 0,
#                 'e': 0
#             }
#             'f' : {
#                 'g': 0
#             }
#         }
#     }
# }
```

You customize each step according to the type you visit each time. This code assumes lists have hashable values, but you can of course extend it.